# Why I'm not rendering this loop correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a component that draws a route and 2 markers on a Map, I have a loop that gets all the positions to draw a marker but I'm not getting the array at time to make a render of the data.

I've tried to put a conditional but doesn't seems to work. The problem is with the state, I put the array into a state but due to the async process I cannot get it at time to render.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import GoogleMapMaker from './GoogleMapMarker';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const GoogleMapsComponent = (props) => {
    const { blackboxLocation, showClaimLocation, showBlackboxLocation } = props;

    const [locationState, setLocationState] = useState([]);
    const [markerArray, setMarkerArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLocationState(blackboxLocation);    
    }, [blackboxLocation]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(locationState) {
            setMarkerArray([locationState[0], locationState[locationState.length]]);
        }
    }, [locationState]);

    const mapProps = {
        center: {
            lat: 59,
            lng: 30
        },
        zoom: 11
    };

    const handleGoogleMap = (google) => {
        const routeProps = new google.maps.Polyline({
            strokeColor: '#081E3E',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 4,
        });

        routeProps.setMap(google.map);


        drawLocationAndCenter(google, routeProps);
    }

    const drawLocationAndCenter = (google, routeProps) => {
        if(showBlackboxLocation) {
            const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            const path = routeProps.getPath();

            markerArray.then((marker) => console.log(marker));

            locationState.then((locations) => {
                locations.map((location) => {
                    const loc = new google.maps.LatLng(location.location.latitude, location.location.longitude);

                    path.push(loc);
                    bounds.extend(loc);

                    return google.map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <GoogleMapReact
            bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AIzaSyCHpeyXo9cKfdgjp-jfyRU52s70UB53D3E' }}
            defaultCenter={mapProps.center}
            defaultZoom={mapProps.zoom}
            yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
            onGoogleApiLoaded={handleGoogleMap}
        >
            { markerArray.length > 0 &&
                markerArray.map(location => (
                    <GoogleMapMaker
                        key={location.rowKey}
                        lat={location.location.latitude}
                        lng={location.location.longitude}
                    />
                ))
            }

        </GoogleMapReact>
    );
    export default GoogleMapsComponent;
```

Comment: You might want to add a [react-hooks] tag to this.

Comment: `locationState[locationState.length]` is out of bounds, although this is probably not the only problem

Comment: I have edited this line with [locationState.length -1] but doesn't change anything

Comment: `if(locationState)` will always be true (an empty `Array` is "truthy" in JavaScript)

Comment: Also, `locationState` is not needed at all, it just reflects the `blackboxLocation` prop.

Comment: Also, `markerArray` is not a state, and no need to use an effect to set it (React calls your function component every time props change)

Comment: What is the type of `blackboxLocation`? You seem to be using it as both an `Array` (in the first effect) and a `Promise` (in `drawLocationAndCenter`)

Comment: `markerArray.then()` will not work as it's an `Array`

Answer (score 0):

Google maps offers up a couple of listeners, you'll need to setstate from those